# Variance of the ratio of numbers of events

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I have the following problem. I have two types of balls (red and blue).
And $N$ bins. The probability of a red ball to go to a bin $k$ is equal to $P_R(k)$,
and the probability of a blue ball to go to the same bin is $P_B(k)$.
These probabilities are known.

Suppose we draw a sample of $N_R$ red balls and $N_B$ blue balls, and 
distribute them randomly among the bins according to their distributions. 
What is the variance of the ratio $X(k)=\frac{n_R(k)}{n_R(k)+n_B(k)}$, 
where $n_R(k)$ and $n_B(k)$ are the numbers of the red and blue balls in the k-th bin?